# Feeding json data from Django into jquery function

Tags: jquery, json, django

I am implementing some jquery code for filtering, which initially takes data from a json file:

```
function getProducts() {
$.get("products.json", (products) => {
  ...;
})
```

However, instead of fetching a json file, I'd like to use a json-like array and use that instead of the json file. This data would come from the Django backend, which would pass the data onto the html template.

Something like this:

```
var products = {{jsonData}}

which would then be this:

var products = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category": "shirts",
    "name": "Fantasy T-shirt",
    "rating": 4,

  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "category": "hoodies",
    "name": "Wolf Hoodie",
    "rating": 5,
  },
]
```

How could I modify the jquery code to accept that?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is that `json-like array` coming from ? not clear what are trying to do ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert *products* (which is a string in your function) to an array? Then use `products = JSON.parse(products)` inside that function. It will work if the json string is valid. See [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I've edited the question. The data would be provided by the Django backend, which would be passed in the correct format. Does that make sense?

Comment: Why not use a `$.each` function in your `$.get` and get all the data from your `array` and then populate it where the data needs to appear.

Comment: @verjas What would be the syntax? Something like below?

$.get(JSON.parse(products), (products) => {

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Json array from view to template by returning it

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

return JsonResponse({'key1':var1})
```

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up question: Where would the json array go inside this code:

```javascript
function getProducts() {
$.get("products.json", (products) => {
  ...;
})
```

Comment: I don't know, sorry :( My javascript skill is less than basic.